# Deploying Django in Apache server

Tags: django, apache

I finished my project in the development server and now I worked it using Apache in the localhost. The project worked good. Now, I got an apache sever. can you please clarify some of my doubts;
1. Need to upload the `Django` installation files, `mod_wsgi` and any other files to the server?
2. Can I maintain the same folder directory as I did with the local host Apache?
3. what is `httpd.conf`, and where can I find it in my server?

I am using *Linux ubuntu OS, Python 2.7, Django 1.6* and my server got its first level of directories like:

> .cpanel, .htpasswords, cpmove.psql, etc, logs, mail, public_ftp, ssl, tmp, www, access-logs and some more .conf and other type files.

Among above directories, I can't open the www folder.

Please suggest any tutorial or some other way to resolve things. It will be very helpful for me and my team.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The django docs have a section on deployment try that one first.

Comment: All those questions are answered separately in different questions in this site or at serverfault or generally accessbile by some googling. But i feel like you should change your general approach. Look into python virtual environments. That should solve the whole installing django thingy...

Comment: thanks a lot.. am diving in. can you please tell me whether its possible with the above mentioned server?